# I want to get all the origin labels that prometheus relabels

Tags: prometheus

As you know, prometheus offers the relabelings which relabels some tricky labels to well-known labels. (ex kubernetes_pod_node_name  to nodename)

But I want to get all the labels that prometheus relabels.

At the target page of prometheus, I could get some of them hovering my cursor on the target.
But whenever I moved the cursor off the target, the list disappears.

Is there any great way to get the origin labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service discovery labels are displayed at `http://your-prometheus.com:9090/service-discovery`, or click `Status->Service discovery` from the main page.

If you want to make some of them visible on actual metrics, here are two examples:

```yaml
relabel_configs:
# make "__meta_something_foo" and "__meta_something_bar" become just "foo" and "bar"
- regex: __meta_something_(foo|bar)
  action: labelmap
# save "__metrics_path__" as "url"
- source_labels: [__metrics_path__]
  target_label: url
```

Comment: I got to know what you answered for me.
But after I added that relabel_configs in servicemonitor (since I use prometheus operator v0.54, prometheus v2.33.1), that target disappeared from prometheus.
I added below
spec:
  endpoints:
  - port: http
    relabelings:
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __(.+)

Comment: @JAESANGPARK I checked it with my local Prometheus, it works as expected (=producing unreadable mess of labels). Though, I configure Prometheus manually, without the operator. Sorry, but I have no idea what happened to your Servicemonitor.

Comment: @JAESANGPARK While I was testing it in my own Prometheus, I made a screenshot for you (added to the answer). I hope it will persuade you against the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
The issue that the target disappears would be because of prometheus operator.
The prometheus operator makes the rule according to the sericemonitor so that the relabelings that I set on the servicemonitor would be overwritten or just appended after the default relabelings.
I should check with just prometheus serevr. thanks

Comment: At prometheus web page, click STATUS -> Service Discovery!!!

Comment: @JAESANGPARK oh, I thought you know that, sorry. Do you mind if I put that into the answer or would you like to answer yourself?

Comment: You could put that into your answer
Ans please check below url. I got tons of information from that blog.
https://grafana.com/blog/2022/03/21/how-relabeling-in-prometheus-works/